# Access to container created by docker-compose in same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image]

As shown in the picture, there are 4 containers. `spider` is created by:

```
docker run xxx --net=dockernet
```

And the `app_xx-server_1/2/3` is created by `docker-compose up` from a directory named `app`, `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  xx-server:
    image: xx-server

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: dockernet
```

And when I start the `spider` and the `app_xx`, I specify the same docker network explicitly(check the ip address in the picture).

Now I want to access the `app_xx-server_1/2/3` from `spider` by http like this:

```
http://app_xx-server
```

It does not work.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly define that the container (xx-server) have the network too:

```
xx-server:
  networks:
    - dockernet
```

Else it won't be available from that container.

Comment: I also think that you might have to use the name `xx-server` as the host, not `app_*` (as defined in the services list) but I might be wrong (not using my regular computer so can't check my own files atm... heh).

Comment: When I fix the `docker-compose.yaml` by adding the network for the `mv-server`, it told me that I use an undefined network.

Comment: Change the key name from `default` to the name of the network. I would recommend not using the "default" network as a external network (never tried it myself, but would guess that it could cause some issues).